# Notify changes in property for Core Data?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

The user will be able to add or change some value (property in my model with Core Data) in one view, when the user switch to another view, I want to show the newly added/changed value with an animation.

Is there a way to get a notification that there has been a change or an update for a property with Core Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at implementing the class method `keyPathsForValuesAffecting<key>`

[Link](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSPersistentDocumentTutorial/03_CustomClass/customClass.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002831-SW4)